# Shell scripts with Scala 2.12.12 broken?

Tags: bash, scala

I have some shell scripts running with Scala 2.12.11. After updating to Scala 2.12.12 they don't do anymore.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "in Bash"
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
object Example { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("in Scala") }
```

Result with Scala 2.12.11:

```
in Bash
in Scala
```

Result with Scala 2.12.12:

```
in Bash
fscbad option: '-Ytrack-dependencies'
  fsc -help  gives more information
error: IO error while decoding /home/marcus/-Ytrack-dependencies with UTF-8: /home/marcus/-Ytrack-dependencies (No such file or directory)
Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
error: IO error while decoding /home/marcus/-Xscript with UTF-8: /home/marcus/-Xscript (No such file or directory)
Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
error: IO error while decoding /home/marcus/Main with UTF-8: /home/marcus/Main (No such file or directory)
Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
three errors found
```

Any idea?

Comment: What happens if you just `scala Script.scala` or if you use `#!/usr/bin/env scala` at the top of the file and skip bash? Or do you need the bash part?

Comment: Yes, I do lots of stuff in the Bash part. Its typically about 40 lines. Some stuff I do: checking if Scala is installed, if it’s the right Scala version, if someone else is running the script already (if it’s single user) and say who and since when, and more. And also I don’t want to annoy the user with details how to run the script. Not cool.

Comment: Got it, however it seems that there is something wrong with that bash part since using exactly the code snippet you posted in your question I can't reproduce the error using either `2.12.11` or `2.13.3`.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling Scala does not stop the compiler daemon. Thus after the update the running daemon does not match the Scala version anymore. Stopping the old daemon (once) with `fsc -shutdown` solves the problem.

Alternatively, you can avoid the daemon altogether by adding `-nocompdaemon` to the `scala` call. Starting with Scala 2.13.0 this is done by default (according to [issue 12102](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12102)).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "in Bash"
exec scala -nocompdaemon "$0" "$@"
!#
object Example { def main(args: Array[String]) = println("in Scala") }
```

Comment: More specifically, "it's necessary to exit the background resident compiler when switching foreground runners"; this happens when the foreground runner is mismatched with an existing background compiler.

Comment: @Joe Good point. I updated my answer accordingly. Also not stopping the daemon on uninstalling Scala seems like the root of this specific problem to me.